# Getting eigenvalues from 3x3 matrix in Python using Power method

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

I'm trying to get all eigenvalues from a 3x3 matrix by using Power Method in Python. However my method returns diffrent eigenvalues from the correct ones for some reason.

My matrix: A = [[1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 5], [3, 5,-1]]

Correct eigenvalues: [ 8.54851285, -4.57408723, 0.02557437 ]

Eigenvalues returned by my method: [ 8.5485128481521926, 4.5740872291939381, 9.148174458392436 ]

So the first one is correct, second one has wrong sign and the third one is all wrong. I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I can't see where have I made mistake.

Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import numpy.linalg as la

eps = 1e-8 # Precision of eigenvalue

def trans(v): # translates vector (v^T)
    v_1 = np.copy(v)
    return v_1.reshape((-1, 1))

def power(A):
    eig = []
    Ac = np.copy(A)
    lamb = 0
    for i in range(3):
        x = np.array([1, 1, 1])
        while True:
            x_1 = Ac.dot(x) # y_n = A*x_(n-1)
            x_norm = la.norm(x_1) 
            x_1 = x_1/x_norm # x_n = y_n/||y_n||
            if(abs(lamb - x_norm) <= eps): # If precision is reached, it returns eigenvalue
                break
            else:
                lamb = x_norm
                x = x_1
        eig.append(lamb)

        # Matrix Deflaction: A - Lambda * norm[V]*norm[V]^T
        v = x_1/la.norm(x_1)
        R = v * trans(v)
        R = eig[i]*R
        Ac = Ac - R

    return eig

def main():
    A = np.array([1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 5, -1]).reshape((3, 3))
    print(power(A))



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

PS. Is there a simpler way to get the second and third eigenvalue from power method instead of matrix deflaction?

Comment: Unless you're doing this for learning purposes, there is already an [existing eigenvalue method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) in `numpy`

Comment: @Petar I know, but I'm doing this for learning purposes. So that eigenvalue method is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With

```
lamb = x_norm
```

you ever only compute the absolute value of the eigenvalues. Better compute them as

```
lamb = dot(x,x_1)
```

where `x` is assumed to be normalized.

As you do not remove the negative eigenvalue -4.57408723, but effectively add it instead, the largest eigenvalue in the third stage is `2*-4.574.. = -9.148..` where you again computed the absolute value.

Comment: You are right. Norm gives me absolute value of my eigenvalue, and when I multiplied my second eigenvalue by (-1) my program worked fine and gave me correct result.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know this method, so I googled it and found here:

http://ergodic.ugr.es/cphys/LECCIONES/FORTRAN/power_method.pdf

that it is valid only for finding the leading (largest) eigenvalue, thus, it seems that it is working for you fine, and it is not guaranteed that the following eigenvalues will be correct.
Btw. `numpy.linalg.eig()` works faster than your code for this matrix, but I am guessing you implemented it as an exercise.

Comment: Yes, I'm implementing this as an exercise and there is a way for Power Method to obtain all eigenvalues using Deflation method described here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/768882/power-method-for-finding-all-eigenvectors but I don't know, why it gives me wrong values.

Comment: Just a thing I noticed, it might be a hint for finding the bug: in your code you are missing (with respect to the math.stack recepie) `R = R/|v|^2` which should not matter, since in your case this norm will always be equal to unity. But then, why is this division still listed in the math.stack recipe? Perhaps it is not unity there, and your line `v = x_1/la.norm(x_1)` is invalid. Just an observation.